# How to use a JOIN in a LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following table structure, which is imported into an Entity Framework project:
(**NOTE**: I mislabled T1Name as T2Name in Table1)

[alt text http://digitalsamurai.us/images/drawing2.png](http://digitalsamurai.us/images/drawing2.png)

I have labeled the Entity Objects.  The many-to-many joint table Table5, is represented as an EntityCollection<Entity4> in Entity3, and as an EntityCollection<Entity3> in Entity4 (EntityCollection<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, so it can be queried).  I need to construct a result set that is:

T1Name, T2Name, T3Name

This will result in repeat entries for T1Name, and T2Name.

Could someone show me how to write this LINQ query?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from e3 in Context.Table3
        from e4 in e3.Table4s     // that's your many-to-many
        select new
        {
            Name3 = e3.T3Name,
            Name2 = e4.Table2.T2Name,
            Name1 = e4.Table1.T1Name // presuming Table1.T2Name in your diagram is a typo
        };
```

"Dot notation":

```
var q = Context.Table3
               .SelectMany(e3 => e3.Select(e4 => 
                                               new {
                                                   Name3 = e3.T3Name,
                                                   Name2 = e4.Table2.T2Name,
                                                   Name1 = e4.Table1.T1Name
                                               });
```

Notice I didn't use `join` at all. That's on purpose; [you don't need it her](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)e.

Comment: Do you know what that would translate into in dot notation?

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I know that the query notation you used above is translated into the form: List.Where(x => x.????).Select(y => y).etc... I was wondering if you knew how your query translated. Just because I am trying to understand LINQ better. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Craig.  Great answer as usual.

Comment: By the way, LINQPad will translate any query into this notation for you, and can use your EF model.